# RestAssured Parsing Json Array Response using foreach loop

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have response from RestAssured which is a JsonArray looks similar to the below code

`[{
    "id": "1",
    "applicationId": "ABC"
        }, {
    "id": "2",
    "applicationId": "CDE"
        }, {
    "id": "3",
    "applicationId": "XYZ"
    }]`

I use code to get the "id" from the first Json element

```
    List<String> jresponse = response.jsonPath().getList("$");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
    String id  = response.jsonPath().getString("id[" + i + "]");
    if(id.equals("1"){
        do something
    }
    else {
        something else
    }

    }
```

Is there a way to use foreach in place of for in the above code?

Comment: Did you use jackson for work with POJO?

Comment: Were you able to check my answer?

Comment: @Fenio The question is how to parse the response directly using foreach. 
The "Identity" class example what you have provided is not what I wanted.

Comment: @MelvinRichard I'll try again then

Comment: @MelvinRichard Check my updated answer again please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of getting the root level like this:

```
List<String> jresponse = response.jsonPath().getList("$");
```

You can grab IDs directly:

```
List<String> ids = path.getList("id");
```

Then, you can use foreach loop, instead of using indexes like this:

```
        List<String> ids = path.getList("id");
        for (String id : ids) {
            if (id.equals("1")) {
                //do something
            } else {
                //do something else
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**

The best way (probably) is to create objects representing the JSON.
In order to do that we have to understand what JSON contains. So far, you have JSON Array which contains JSON Objects. Each of JSON Object contain `id` and `applicationId`. In order to parse this JSON into a Java class we have to create a class. Let's call it `Identity`. You can call it whatever you want.

```
public class Identity {
    public String id;
    public String applicationId;
}
```

The above is the representation of JSON Object. Field names are exact names in JSON. Identifiers should be public.

Now, to parse JSON into Java classes we can use `JsonPath` like this:

```
Identity[] identities = path.getObject("$", Identity[].class);
```

Then, we iterate over the array to get what we want:

```
        for (Identity identity : identities) {
            if (identity.id.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println(identity.applicationId);
            }
        }
```

Based on that you can create a full method instead of just printing the `applicationId` like this:

```
    private static String getApplicationId(String id, Identity[] identities) {
        for (Identity identity : identities) {
            if (identity.id.equals(id)) {
                return identity.applicationId;
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot find applicationId for id: " + id);
    }
```

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

In order to use `foreach` and get `applicationID` based on `id` you need to use `getList` method but in different manner.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> responseMap = response.jsonPath().getList("$");
```

In the above code, we get the list of JSON Objects in the JSON Array.

Each of the elements in the HashMap is a single JSON Object. Strings are the attributes like `id` and `applicationId` and second `String` are the values of each attribute.

Now, we can use `foreach` loop like this to get desired results:

```
private static String getApplicationIdBasedOnId(Response response, String id) {
    List<HashMap<String, String>> responseMap = response.jsonPath().getList("$");
    for (HashMap<String, String> singleObject : responseMap) {
        if (singleObject.get("id").equals(id)) {
             return singleObject.get("applicationId");
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot find applicationId for id: " + id);
}
```

Comment: The question is if the id is equal to 1,  then how to get the particular applicationId?

Comment: @MelvinRichard Give me 5 minutes, I'll update my answer

Comment: @Fenio - what if the response is just a simple array of numbers ? Can I get the root element directly as a Java array ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 you can get any root element with `$` using Rest Assured's JSON path. `List<Integer> numbers = path.getList("$");`